# How to replace all numbers in java string

Tags: java, regex

I have string like this String `s="ram123",d="ram varma656887"`
I want string like ram and ram varma so how to seperate string from combined string
I am trying using regex but it is not working

```
PersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor
                .getColumnName(1))).replaceAll("[^0-9]+"));
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The correct RegEx for selecting all numbers would be just `[0-9]`, you can skip the `+`, since you use `replaceAll`.

However, your usage of `replaceAll` is wrong, it's defined as follows: [`replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)). The correct code in your example would be: `replaceAll("[0-9]", "")`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following regex: `\d` for representing numbers. In the regex that you use, you have a `^` which will check for any characters other than the charset `0-9`

```
    String s="ram123";
    System.out.println(s);
    /* You don't need the + because you are using the replaceAll method */
    s = s.replaceAll("\\d", "");  // or you can also use [0-9]
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: What about consecutive occurrences of numbers? If the example is `string1234value5678`. Wouldn't `\\d+` replace it to `stringvalue` in two iterations, instead of replacing it 8 times with `\\d`?

Answer (score 3):

To remove the numbers, following code will do the trick.

```
 stringname.replaceAll("[0-9]","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do as follows

```
String name = "ram varma656887";
    name = name.replaceAll("[0-9]","");
    System.out.println(name);//ram varma
```

alternatively you can do as

```
 String name = "ram varma656887";
         name = name.replaceAll("\\d","");
          System.out.println(name);//ram varma
```

also something like given will work for you

```
String given = "ram varma656887";

    String[] arr = given.split("\\d");
    String data = new String();
    for(String x : arr){

        data = data+x;
    }

    System.out.println(data);//ram varma
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed the second argument of replace all. You need to put a empty string as argument 2 instead of actually leaving it empty.

try

```
replaceAll(<your regexp>,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Java - String replaceAll() Method.
This method replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

*Here is the syntax of this method:*

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

*Here is the detail of parameters:*

**regex** -- the regular expression to which this string is to be matched.

**replacement** -- the string which would replace found expression.

*Return Value:*

This method returns the resulting String.

for your question use this

```
    String s = "ram123", d = "ram varma656887";
    System.out.println("s" + s.replaceAll("[0-9]", ""));
    System.out.println("d" + d.replaceAll("[0-9]", ""));
```